# How to test with api-designer (RAML editor)?

Tags: api, raml

Just like postman does, does api-designer support that?

I try to POST my request to my service (127.0.0.1:8180) and if I click 'API is behind a firewall', it POST http://127.0.0.1:8180/v1/device，and the response is:

```
Status
0
Headers
```

If uncheck 'API is behind a firewall', it POST **/proxy**/http://127.0.0.1:8180/v1/device, and the response is

```
Status
404

Headers
connection: 
keep-alive
content-length: 
51
content-type: 
text/html; charset=utf-8
date: 
Fri, 09 Sep 2016 14:24:06 GMT
x-content-type-options: 
nosniff
x-powered-by: 
Express
Body

Cannot POST /proxy/http://127.0.0.1:8180/v1/device

1
Cannot POST /proxy/http://127.0.0.1:8180/v1/device
```

Answer (score 0):

CozyAzure.

Unfortenly, api-designer has several problems with the proxy. I didn't spend much time for the issue and started to use postman collections for this. You can [Importing RAML folders as Collections](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/importing_folders) and make a request with postman.

Comment: Would be nice to understand what problems you had, maybe through a Github issue? :)